# Why is this a non-reducing end?

Tags: biochemistry

[image]

I was told that C is a non-reducing end. To my understanding, only anomeric carbon involved in glycosidic bond cannot be in the linear form, and in other words, is a non-reducing end. But C is an anomeric carbon for that monosaccharide in that particular structure and it is a free and unsubstituted anomeric carbon which should be the reducing end, so why is C a non-reducing end instead? Or am I being told the wrong answer?

Comment: I'll give you my humble opinion, perhaps waiting for other more correct answers: I think carbon C is certainly reducing, as it is a hemiacetal, therefore it can de-cyclize, regenerate the carbonyl group, which can then be reduced (for example from Fehling's reagent). In my opinion the question of the non-reducing refers to the entire molecule: in carbohydrates with many monomers the reducing portion is infinitely tiny compared to the non-reducing portion, so the molecule can be considered overall non-reducing.

Comment: In fact, if I'm not mistaken, Fehling's reagent does not work on polysaccharides, even though they have a single reducing end.

Comment: I meant oxidized from Fehling*